# Carrierwave files with Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, carrierwave

I'm using rails 3.2 with asset and  carrierwave for upload some images, they store in /public/uploads/photo/..... 
but when I do a cap:deploy (with capistrano) my current directory application doesn't contain the files I uploaded, because capistrano make a new version ....

=== Update ===

After all I use this :

inside :deploy namespace

```
   task :symlink_uploads do
     run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/uploads  #{release_path}/public/uploads"
   end
```

and after:

```
after 'deploy:update_code', 'deploy:symlink_uploads'
```

=== Re Update ===

The solution of @tristanm is the best way to solve this.

Comment: well, as you could see, the solution isn't  in the answers... So, I dont know if I have to choice one.

Comment: Use `deploy:finishing` for Capistrano 3+

Answer (score 65, accepted):

How about this:

```
# config/deploy.rb
set :shared_children, shared_children + %w{public/uploads}
```

`:shared_children` defaults to `%w(public/system log tmp/pids)` so we're just expanding this list.

**EDIT:**

Don't forget to run `cap deploy:setup` after changing `:shared_children` so that the new targets are created under `shared`.

**EDIT Capistrano 3:**

Capistrano 3 uses the `linked_dirs` setting and doesn't specify `public/system` as a default anymore.

`set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs) + %w{public/system public/uploads}`

Comment: It did created the uploads folder inside shared, but the files aren't save there. am I missing a step?

Comment: Could be that the symlinks haven't been created. Run `cap deploy` again and check that `releases/current/public/uploads` is a symlink to `shared/uploads`. Also, make sure you're not using a really ancient version of Capistrano.

Comment: I think that your solution looks great but really I didn't try that way, so for the amount of UP votes, I will give you the "accept". Thanks

Comment: Thanks! Worked, though I had to redeploy whole application from scratch. Simple cap deploy:setup did not work.

Comment: I am using capistrano 3. I only added this line to deploy.rb set :linked_dirs, %w{public/uploads}. Got an error when using the fetch(:linked_dirs) part.

Answer (score 5):

**With Capistrano 3** and without needing to redeploy.

Like @tristanm mentioned add this to your config/deploy.rb

```
# config/deploy.rb
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs) + %w{public/uploads}
```

To have capistrano create shared/public/uploads

`cap deploy:check:linked_dirs`

Now cap can create the symlink

`cap deploy:symlink:shared`

Finally, if you have backups of the uploads you can put them in shared/public/uploads/ and they should work without needing to redeploy.

Comment: Thanks Jason, I will try this on Capistrano 3.

Answer (score 4):

Capistrano creates new directory for every deploy.

There are some exceptions to it. For example, the log files are shared between the deployment directories because they are just symlinks. You have to create a symlink for public/uploads as well.

Here is the command:

```
run <<-CMD
  rm -rf #{latest_release}/public/uploads &&
  ln -s #{shared_path}/uploads #{latest_release}/public/uploads
CMD
```

Comment: I have to put this in a Capistrano task?

Answer (score 0):

**Go to your app server shared folder and create an uploads directory.**

mkdir uploads

**In your deploy.rb file insert these codes under deploy namespace**

task :symlink_uploads do

run "rm -rf #{latest_release}/public/uploads && ln -nfs #{shared_path}/uploads #{latest_release}/public/uploads"

end

after 'deploy:update_code', 'deploy:symlink_uploads'

Now delete the old files present already as they won't work. Upload a new file and cap deploy your app again. It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Using Capistrano 3, I just added this line to my config/deploy.rb

```rb
set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system public/uploads}
```

Then, run:

```
$ cap production deploy
```