# Rails 3.2 Asset Pipeline, CarrierWave and .gitignore

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, carrierwave, gitignore

I'm using CarrierWave gem and Rails 3.2. When in production, Rails requires me to pre-compile the user image folder.

Currently my CarrierWave upload images to public/assets/images and I'm ignoring public folder in .gitignore.

Is there a better practice for this?

Answer (score 0):

[This question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9043662/carrierwave-files-with-capistrano) provide you with better options for managing CarrierWave upload images