# ckeditor assets removed after cap deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

I have used Rails 4.0.0,

After cap deploy the ckeditor assets are being removed from server.

can anybody please help.

These are the codes in **deploy.rb**

```
# if you want to clean up old releases on each deploy uncomment this:
after "deploy:restart", "deploy:cleanup", 'deploy:update_crontab'



namespace :deploy do
  task :start, :roles => :app do
    run "touch #{current_path}/tmp/restart.txt"
  end

  task :stop, :roles => :app do
    # Do nothing.
  end

  desc "Restart Application"
  task :restart, :roles => :app do
    run "touch #{current_path}/tmp/restart.txt"
  end

  after 'deploy:update_code' do
    #run "cd #{release_path}; RAILS_ENV=production rake db:create"

    run "cd #{release_path}; RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate"
    run "cd #{release_path}; RAILS_ENV=production rake db:seed"
    run "cd #{release_path}; RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile"

    run "ln -s #{shared_path}/public/ckeditor_assets #{release_path}/public/ckeditor_assets"

  end

  desc "Update the crontab file"
  task :update_crontab, :roles => :db do
    run "cd #{release_path} && whenever --update-crontab #{application}"
    run "cd #{release_path}; tail -f log/cron_log.log"
  end
```

Comment: they are removed from the shared folder or what?

Comment: May be.. but how can i accomplish that?

Comment: accomplish what? i was asking you where the files got removed. from the shared folder? are they not linked to into the app? are they just missing in the browser?

Comment: @phoet: ohh .. folders get removed after each deploy and I am not getting any folder inside shared to link those ckeditor_assets folder in releases ...

Comment: what do you mean by "getting any folder inside shared"? you need to put your files into that folder so that capistrano can symlink the folder into your current release directory.

Answer (score 2):

This happend because the files are stores in the application folder (public), and you needs to move to shared.

You have two options: 
- Make a receipe to symlink your files to share
- Include your folder to shared

You can see about this steps here: [Carrierwave files with Capistrano](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9043662/carrierwave-files-with-capistrano)